# Root directory/Archive file not found while importing

Tags: android

I am trying to import a archive file containing Android application project in *Eclipse*. But I receive a message **No projects are found to import**. Same goes when I am importing a root directory. Why I am getting this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project in question may not have been set up to work with Eclipse. For example, it might not have `.classpath` and `.project` files.

If so, you can still "import" it into an Android project -- start a new Android project and choose "Create project from existing source".